# Error al compilar java en JCreator Pro

Tags: java, jcreator

tengo este problema al tratar de compilar un archivo java en Jcreator, que puede ser?

[image: Problema con JCreator]

Comment: Al parecer no es problema de compilación sino de ejecución. ¿Te funciona para algun otro archivo java? Tal vez no esta bien configurado el jdk/jre en ese editor.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, solo me faltaba crear un proyecto al parecer